# angular combine a uniue code with existing css class how can i modified it

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I use ngx-skeleton-loader and I want to modify add color. but I can't   
[Here image regarding the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeONq.png)

On the developer tool, you see the styles action in the styles action bar

> .loader[_ngcontent-gaw-c19]

(angular generate the unique id (_ngcontent-**gaw**-c19  )  this **_ngcontent-** static id given by angular at a one-time particular div.
and **-gaw-** is dynamic and this change every time when a page refresh, then I want to modify the existing CSS how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can add CSS only by _ngcontent. You should use instead another selector. Sorry about that :(